# Is there a prebuilt website with logins I can work from? (Just starting to use javascript)

Tags: javascript

I need to build a website that allows users to upload files and a few other actions.  I have zero experience with javascript so I was wondering if there was some type of built site that already had logins coded so I could just work on the other logic?

I'm a long time delphi developer so I'm not new to programming.  Any javascript video references would be great as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your logins should ***not*** be handled by JavaScript. You should choose  a server side language such as Ruby or PHP.

Comment: look into the django framework...a few other frameworks will get you similar authentication ffeatures....asp mvc does as well i believe

Comment: @Matt JS is no longer just a client-side technology. It's perfectly acceptable to have a server-side JS login handler.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to be handling logins with plain-old JavaScript unless you start building a super cool NodeJS setup, which, I wouldn't recommend if you have zero experience with JavaScript.

To ease your JS adventure, check out [JQuery.com](http://www.jquery.com) which makes it easier to code JS without worrying so much about browser quirks.

For easy server-side login, I recommend PHP since there are literally millions of tutorials and free code snippets out there, hosting is cheap, and an enormous community of PHP developers online to help you. To ease your PHP adventure, start with a framework such as [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com).

To answer your question, here's an example of a PHP + JavaScript (JQuery) login solution: http://blog.webwizo.com/2011/05/04/simple-login-with-php-and-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload files, you'll need a server-sided script, possibly done in PHP.

As for communicating with the server, it can be somewhat daunting for a beginner, but it's largely done via `xmlhttprequest` (otherwise known as AJAX).
Here's a tutorial on how to use it by W3CSchools, but there are plenty more on the net: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

One word of advice; don't make the mistake of relying of a JS library too soon; familiarize yourself with the language and its capabilities. A lot of answerers are just going to say "Use JQuery." You can (and possibly should), but it's important to know how Javascript works without it.

Comment: PS: I can also send you some sample code if you would like of a PHP/Javascript method of modifying a text file on a server: just shoot me an email.

Comment: [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: +1 for preventing new JS people to use libraries without prior deep knowledge about JS.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Interesting... of course most of my Javascript knowledge was acquired by unofficial blogs ;) Edit: I do blame it for making me think that `setTimeout` required a string argument early on >:(

Comment: @JeffreySweeney, just a side note, whenever you search JS stuff on search engines make sure to add `MDN` at the end, this will make your life easier. `example "array mdn"`. The top results will be from the official and trustable mozilla documentation